# Forward button functionality in the Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, user-interface

l was watching one of the Play Store app videos on Note 3 and accidentally touched the back button twice. And That's when I realized HARD one more time that I can not do a forward (back to what I was watching). As a result, I could not locate that app again.

This ( not being able to go forward ) becomes an issue on many other situations too..

So, forward button is definitely has its own place in the UX. ( Imagine not having the forward button on the internet browsers, that's exactly the situation here. )

Is there a history of visited apps on the play store on the device that I can navigate back *and forward* through?

Comment: That's an interesting question, and I agree that it would be nice to have a forward button in the play store. Browsers, however, actually **do** have forward buttons if their devs allow it. [Here's an example](http://i.imgur.com/n2zvCbe.png) using Chrome.

Comment: thx dotVezz. The reason I brought up the internet browser's forward button talk into my question was to make a point about the forward button's place in UX world in general. There, I tried to say how the life would have sucked without that functionality in browsing the Internet. I knew that the internet browsers on the device (not just chrome but all) have their own little back & forward functionality . Thank you for the screenshow anyway though. I appreciate it. I think an overall ( device level ) forward button functionality has to be somehow worked out.

Comment: An OS-level forward button would almost certainly not be a good idea in a practical sense. The idea of it is good, but the functionality is up to the app developers for a reason.

Comment: For me, your rant about wanting a forward button really detracts from what would otherwise be a useful question about seeing your Play Store history.

Comment: Dan, I agree. That rant was not necessary.